# some error without reason

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I just start to work with this code but it is not running?!

Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {y[x]^2 - ((1/52)*Sqrt[3]*y[x])*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + (x)^-2/1000 - (69/100)] + ((49 (x)^-2)/100000) - (69/100) == 0} /. x -> x[t];y0 = 71;
eqns2 = eqns /. y[x[t]] :> x'[t]/(y0*x[t]);

sol = NDSolve[Append[eqns2, x[1] == 1], x, {t, 1, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}], FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, x})]

Plot[Evaluate[x'[t]/y0*x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}], FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, y})]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], x'[t]/y0*x[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}], FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x[t], y[t]})]

Comment: Need a space between products.  Above you have (y0x[t]).  Need (y0 x[t]).  Also, some may complain this is part of the other thread regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
eqns = {y[x]^2 - ((1/52)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]) Sqrt[
       y[x]^2 + (x)^-2/1000 - (69/100)] + ((49 (x)^-2)/100000) - (69/100) == 
    0} /. x -> x[t]; y0 = 71; eqns2 = eqns /. y[x[t]] :> x'[t]/(y0 x[t]);
```

Use arbitrary-precision

```
sol = NDSolve[Append[eqns2, x[1] == 1], x, {t, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Note the domains of each of the solutions.

Since the `NDSolve` is defined for `{t, 1, 10}`, each of the plots should be restricted to that interval.

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol[[{4, 1}]]], {t, 1, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{sol4, sol1}, {.8, .35}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, x})]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[x'[t]/y0*x[t] /. sol[[{4, 1}]]],
 {t, 1, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{sol4, sol1}, {.8, .35}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, y})]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], x'[t]/y0*x[t]} /. sol[[{4, 1}]]],
 {t, 1, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{sol4, sol1}, {.8, .5}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x[t], y[t]})]
```

[image]